# How to add permanent route AFTER VPN up?

Tags: vpn, static-routes

I have a server with a vpn (is vpn server also).

For some reasons the vpn is disconnecting occasionally.

I have a route that i add manually afte getting up as I need to see from the server (cloud) the internal network, after the vpn.

So i add this : `route add -net 192.168.54.0/24 gw 10.50.20.2`  manually 
every time after vpn goes up.

I tried to add this in the /etc/network/interfaces (yes its debian)

```
up route add -net 192.168.54.0/24 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.50.20.2

down route del -net 192.168.54.0/24 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.50.20.2
```

but it never gets up automatically.. I assume i do something wrong.

So i want this route to come up when the vpn is connected.

Please can somebody help

many thanks

Comment: Why don't you add the route to your VPN server config?

Comment: can you help me a bit please on this? have no idea where to add it...

Comment: What do you use? OpenVPN? IPSec? x?

Comment: Installed with this script https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn . as it says "We will use Libreswan as the IPsec server, and xl2tpd as the L2TP provider. "  can you please help??? hundreds of thanks

Comment: anybody can help pleasE?

Comment: can somebody please help ???? thank you in advance!